# How to add a new button class to jQuery theme

Tags: addclass, jquery-ui-button

I'm a newbie to jQuery so bear with me. I want to add a separate button class but can't make the hover  and default work together  for a new button  class.
ui-button-blue is the default and uses a blue gradient background image.
ui-button-orange is the hover and uses an orange gradient background image.

I can force the new default blue button to appear properly, by resetting the css attributes for ui-button-blue for the default ui-button attributes for my theme--but the hover only applies the border attribute (orange) and not the new orange background image.

I can make the ui-button-orange (hover) work by resetting the ui-button back to its theme default.

This css makes the button-orange work for hover if the ui-button is set for the theme default:

```
.ui-state-hover, 
.ui-button-orange { 
    border: 1px solid #ff7f00; 
    height: 24px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin-right: .1em; 
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-align: center; 
    zoom: 1; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    *overflow: visible; 
    background-image: url(images/ but_01_orange.png); 
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
    color:#fff; 
}
```

But I can't get them to work together. I have tried some custom .js  to over ride the jQuery css and .js but can't get this to work either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").button();
    $("button").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass();
           $(this).addClass('ui-button-orange ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all  ui-button-text-only ui-button-blue');//hover
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass();
            $(this).addClass('ui-button-blue ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only-ui-button-blue');
        }
    );
});
```